# Can't send mail through php mail() function

Tags: php, html

I tried to send an email through php mail() function but it fails to send the mail. the code i tried is

```
<?php
    if( isset($_REQUEST['send_button']) ){
        $id = "example@example.com";
        $subject = "Sample Mail";
        $message = "This is test message";
        $headers = "From: Giridharan";
        if( mail($id, $subject, $message, $headers) === true ){ echo "mail sent"; }
    }

    if( isset($_REQUEST['staff']) ){
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action='send_mail.php'>
        Staff ID :<input type='text' name='to' value=<?php echo $_REQUEST['staff'];  ?> readonly style="border:none" size:30 /><br />
        Subject:<input type='text' name='subject' size:30 /><br />
        Content:<textarea name='content'></textarea><br />
        <input type='submit' name='send_button' value='Send' />
        <button type=button name='cancel_button'>Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php 
   }else{
        echo  " Select a staff to mail";
   }  
?>
```

I didn't get any errors and the statement "mail sent" is successfully echoed but it doesn't arrives at my mail box.

Comment: Check the mail log on your webserver and on your mail server. If you don't get a false return from mail, then php gave the mail to something and it is now a problem with that something rather than php

Comment: you should look into using this class https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey PHPMailer is not a must.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor no but its a great class to use so you aren't manually writing headers, if there is a problem sending mail using mail you can also use smtp etc etc.

Comment: I think `Staff ID` input is wrong.

Comment: @GiriDharan Beside checking server log , check junk box as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about guessing error sources.

Comment: Rather than PHPMailer, SwiftMailer is a better choice with extended features.

Comment: Your `<form action='send_mail.php'>` is invalid. Try `<form action="send_mail.php" method="POST">` **or** `<form action="" method="POST">` if all code is on the same page.

Comment: Is the to address being passed correctly?

Comment: Try sending `mail()` without the `if` condition and variables, just to test. Also check the spam folder of the receiving email. Php `mail()` seems to get treated as spam frequently.

Comment: *sidenote:* Make sure you quote all the HTML attributes with single quotes / double quotes .

Comment: If you are specifying different page for form submit then make sure that the mail code is on that page and not on the same page

Comment: So, what's inside `send_mail.php` then? The problem may lie in there (big question mark)

Comment: Try adding `\r\n` to your headers. And are you testing this via the Web or `localhost`? You're not making proper use of header information.

Comment: @Fred send_mail.php is the script what i have posted here

Comment: @GiriDharan Well then (for one thing), you should use `<action=""` then, as I previously stated in my (deleted) answer. Or `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"`. And not `send_mail.php`. Have you not read the PHP manual on the subject? >>> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php (headers)

Comment: @Fred sry to mention that i m trying from localhost

Comment: @GiriDharan Oh, **now** you tell me. I guess I should've asked in the first place. I think that's what I'll do from hereonin, for anyone else posting questions about **forms**. You should've also included that in your question, and post it if a similar occasion ever presents itself. It will make a huge difference.

Comment: @GiriDharan Irrelant yes. This `<button type=button name='cancel_button'>Cancel</button>`. Enclose your type to `type='button'`.

Comment: ^-- I meant **Irrelevant**, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIFT MAILER MAKES THE PROCESS SIMPLER. HERE IS THE WORKING CODE

```
        require_once 'swift/lib/swift_required.php';
        // Create the SMTP configuration
        $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mailout.one.com',25);
          $transport->setUsername('YOURMAIL@EMAIL.COM');
          $transport->setPassword('YOUR PASSWORD');

        // Create the message
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
        $message->setTo(array(
           "TO_ADDRESS@EMAIL.COM"

        ));

        $message->setSubject("This is a test message ");
        $message->setBody("This is an automatically genrated message kindly do not reply.");
        $message->setFrom("YOURMAIL@EMAIL.COM", "YOUR PASSWORD");



        // Send the email
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
        $mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);

        // Show failed recipients
        print_r($failedRecipients);
```